# How do I change the button text color on my header?

Tags: customization

So I'm looking at my header in Wordpress and I noticed the header button text color is stuck on black. I don't know any way to change this since I'm very new to wordpress; and any other answers I found online either were outdated or not relevant. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Hi, which theme you have to use? and you know about css?

Comment: Can you share your website and button where locate?